# Update shadow layer when orientation changing

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UICollectionView` with shadow on its cells. I use

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.rotate), name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
func rotate() {
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

and in `layoutSubviews()` I reload this shadow. In cells, which is appearing on the screen all is good, in cells, which is far all is good too, but cells, which existed, but which is out of the screen (right up or down) is not updated.

Why is it, and how I can resolve this problem?

Here is my update shadow code:

```
circleShadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: circleShadowView.bounds, cornerRadius: circleShadowView.bounds.width / 2).cgPath
circleShadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
circleShadowView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addRect(circleShadowView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -30))
path.addRoundedRect(in: circleShadowView.bounds, cornerWidth: circleShadowView.bounds.width / 2, cornerHeight: circleShadowView.bounds.width / 2)
maskLayer.path = path
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

circleShadowView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```